# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на div1 появлялся на экране div2(div2 изначально скрыт), а при повторном нажатии div2 исчезал?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на div1 появлялся на экране div2(div2 изначально скрыт), а при повторном нажатии div2 исчезал?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на CSS

```css
#block {
  display: none;
}

label[for="block"]::after {
  content: 'Показать блок';
  display: inline;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#block_hidden {
  display: none;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

#block:checked ~ label[for="block"]::after {
  content: 'Спрятать блок';
  color: red;
}

#block:checked ~ #block_hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="block">
<label for="block"></label>
<div id="block_hidden">Скрытый блок</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener( 'click' , function(e) {
   e.target.classList.toggle('active');
   document.querySelector('.panel').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Пример - http://www.jooom.ru/toster/vanilla10.php